# SQL syntax ip.board clueless

Tags: mysql

I have a problem out of nothing mysql is returning the following error.
Using ip.board forum software

```
Date: Fri, 06 Nov 2020 00:00:51 +0000
```

Error: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '))) and topic_id=8380 AND  queued IN (0,1,2)  ORDER BY pid asc LIMIT 0,20 ) z...' at line 1
IP Address:  - /index.php?/topic/8380-official-pandoriumx-tracker/?p=1472739

```
mySQL query error: SELECT p.*,m.member_id as mid,m.name,m.member_group_id,m.email,m.joined,m.posts, m.last_visit, m.last_activity,m.login_anonymous,m.title as member_title, m.warn_level, m.warn_lastwarn, m.members_display_name, m.members_seo_name, m.member_banned, m.has_gallery, m.has_blog, m.members_bitoptions,m.mgroup_others,pp.*,w.wl_id,pc.*,rep_index.rep_rating as has_given_rep,rep_cache.rep_points, rep_cache.rep_like_cache,cca.*,ccb.cache_content as cache_content_sig, ccb.cache_updated as cache_updated_sig FROM ( SELECT pid, post_date FROM ipbposts WHERE ((upper(post) not like '%PREMIUM%' and upper(post) not like '%DONAT%') or (pid in (select p_id from ipbcore_sys_bandp)) or (author_id in ())) and topic_id=8380 AND  queued IN (0,1,2)  ORDER BY pid asc LIMIT 0,20 ) z  LEFT JOIN ipbposts p ON ( p.pid=z.pid )
```

anyone knows how to fix this query? iam literally clueless

Comment: The very first thing you can do, to help us understand your question, is to format the SQL query across multiple lines, so that we can read it.

Comment: Looks like an empty `IN ()`, here `(author_id in ()))` ?

Comment: can you give me a hint to fix this?